# Scheduled WebJob deployed via Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 results in On Demand Job

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I'm using VS 2013 Update 4. I have a web job like below.  After I did Publish as Azure WebJobs from Visual Studio, the job became "On Demand".  Is there way to get around this today?  Thank you.

P.S. Is there way to modify the WebJob inside the Azure Portal?  Right clicking on the job only showed Run and Delete.

**Edit**: I noticed a couple of things hours later.  First, interestingly I just found the "On Demand" job was actually running at my specified interval.  Secondly logging back to the original azure management site it was showing my job as "Scheduled" while the new portal showing it as "On Demand".  Is this a typo in the new azure portal?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "MyJob",
  "startTime": "2015-06-05T12:15:00-08:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Hour",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

Comment: I suspect you have 5 scheduled jobs right now and this one is #6 that violates limitation of free scheduler (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/scheduler/) that is in use at the background here. This case switching your job to OnDemand is a default behavior

If I'm wrong - I would start with re-deploying your job with desired settings

Comment: @Igor thank you for pointing that limit out, but I just have this one job.  I just added some comments above and found that the old portal showing it correctly as "Scheduled" but the new Azure Portal is showing my job as "On Demand".  But what matters is that it was running :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the new Azure portal doesn't support scheduled WebJobs.
So you can't create a scheduled WebJob there and it will not recognize a WebJob that has a scheduler job associated with it.

So for now please use the current Azure portal for managing scheduled WebJobs.

Comment: Thank you Amit.  Is it safe to say I can still deploy from VS the way I'm doing since the old portal shows correctly and the new portal will catch up?

Comment: Yes, it certainly is.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/ (not really an answer but I don't know when/if there will be support for scheduled webjobs in the new portal).